# Why is my php code not giving me the right text field name

Tags: php, html, input, naming

I am trying to make a web application that stores and retrieves race information. I am creating the text inputs dynamically by using a php function and index looping.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    function table_head()
    {
        if ( func_num_args() > 0 )
        {
            $args = func_get_args();
            foreach($args as $value)
            {
                echo "<th>" . $value . "</th>";
            } 
        }
    }


    function display_fields()
    {
        $i = 0;
        $a = 19;
        $name="hi";
        while($i++ < $a)
        {
            array_push($numbers,$i);
            if($i==1)
            {  
                $name = "time";
            } else if($i > 1 && $i < 19){
                $name = "lap" + strval($i);
            } else {
                $name = "avgspd";
            } 
            echo "<td><input type='text' size='7' name='" . $name . "'/></td>";
        }   
    }   

echo "<form action='' method='POST'>";
    echo "<table><tr>";
    table_head("Time","lap1","lap2","lap3","lap4","lap5","lap6","lap7","lap8","lap9","lap10","lap11","lap12","lap13","lap14","lap15","lap16","lap17","Avg Spd");
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    display_fields();
    echo "</tr></table><br><input type='submit'/></form>";

?>
```

Why is it that the name of the textfield is called "1","2" etc. instead of "lap1","lap2"?
Is there a way how I can fix this? If so how?

This is what the browser (Safari 8.0.7 OS X version) shows for the source code:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>lap1</th>
            <th>lap2</th>
            <th>lap3</th>
            <th>lap4</th>
            <th>lap5</th>
            <th>lap6</th>
            <th>lap7</th>
            <th>lap8</th>
            <th>lap9</th>
            <th>lap10</th>
            <th>lap11</th>
            <th>lap12</th>
            <th>lap13</th>
            <th>lap14</th>
            <th>lap15</th>
            <th>lap16</th>
            <th>lap17</th>
            <th>Avg Spd</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='time'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='2'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='3'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='4'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='5'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='6'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='7'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='8'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='9'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='10'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='11'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='12'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='13'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='14'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='15'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='16'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='17'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='18'/></td>
            <td><input type='text' size='7' name='avgspd'/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><br><input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

Note: This code I found via safari's web inspector was all on one line, I formatted it like this to make the code easier for you to inspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$name = "lap" . strval($i);
```

PHP uses `.` to concatenate strings, not `+`.

Comment: Thanks. I remembered `.` for most concatenations, however python some reason got to my mind then!

Comment: I tried to. When I did it said you must wait 10mins.